# Magento 2 : How to display product name in custom tab in admin grid?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, magento2.3, ui-form

I want to display the product name in custom tab form on admin grid and
you can see the form image I have added below.
[image]

Comment: Please explain a bit more in your question.

Comment: in custom tab form that you can see in the image there i want to display the particular product name in the form

Answer (score 0):

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'field_name',
    'label',
    [
        'name' => 'field_name',
        'label' => __('Productname'),
        'title' => __('Product Name'),
        'renderer'  => 'VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Extension\Grid\Renderer\Productname',
    ]
);
```

**Define Render :-**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Extension\Grid\Renderer;

class Produtcname extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer {



    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context,

        array $data = []) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->_authorization = $context->getAuthorization();
    }
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row) {
        //write your code
    }

}
```